# max min sum printing can be simplify in fewer lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(max(digits))
print(min(digits))
print(sum(digits))
```

Is it Possible to simply print code line into one?

Comment: `print(max(digits), min(digits), sum(digits), sep='\n')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in 2 lines by combining the `print` statements:

```
digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(max(digits),min(digits),sum(digits))
```

Or alternatively split it by new lines:

```
print(max(digits), min(digits), sum(digits), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```py
print(max(digits), min(digits), sum(digits))
print('{}\n{}\n{}'.format(max(digits), min(digits), sum(digits)))
```

The first method prints all the results separated by a space. The second line
prints every digit on a second line like the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following:

```
digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(max(digits), min(digits), sum(digits))
```

I am not completely sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Using *f string***

```
print(f"{max(digits)}\n{min(digits)}\n{sum(digits)}")
```